# Eloquent - Get records by day

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I have a list of database records that represent some events. Each has a `start_time` column that contains dates in this format: `2017-10-28 22:00:00`. I would like to be able to get all the records whose column `start_time` is a Friday using Laravel. Something like this:

```php
$fridayEvents = $q->whereDate('start_time', '=', isFriday());
```

But I am having a hard time creating `isFriday()` with Carbon.

Comment: hii.. can you please explain what you have in `start_time` string 'friday' or boolean value??

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid `start_time` contains datetime like this `2017-10-28 22:00:00`

Comment: ok so now you need to check that on which day this date falls?? if I am going somewhere wrong pls help me to get clear view of your question so that I could help you

Comment: Yes I'd like to be able to get all records whose date is this friday, not the one of next week. Also the records of this saturday and so on

Comment: ok is it a iterative process or just for once?

Comment: Just once I guess

Comment: ok I have psuedocode for understanding pls check my answer

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Leo have you tried my answer what did you got from it?

Comment: does my answer solved your issue??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL (and other SQLs) implement the [WEEKDAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function that extracts the weekday from a date:

> WEEKDAY(**date**)
>
> Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 =
>   Sunday).
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT WEEKDAY('2008-02-03 22:23:00');
>         -> 6
> mysql> SELECT WEEKDAY('2007-11-06');
>         -> 1
> ```

So you can do a query like this:

```
$q->whereRaw('WEEKDAY(your_table_name.start_date) = 4')
```

This way is more efficient then filtering results directly on PHP using Carbon:

- You will process data using native database functions that are faster then Carbon over PHP.
- Only the relevant data will travel from Database to PHP, reducing query time and memory usage

To get the top performance, you'll need to create a column to store the weekday, so your database will be able to use indexes to avoid full-table scan, giving you the best performance.

Comment: Thanks but the original idea was to get the records of `this` friday. Not the one in 3 weeks or 2 weeks ago

Answer (score 1):

`whereDate()` will only check the dates, so you can't check day with `whereDate()`

For achieving your goal, you need to perform couple of operations, I am using psuedocode as I don't know how you are querying.

```
$records = Event::get();
$filteredArray = array();
foreach($records as $record){
    if(Carbon::parse($record->start_time)->dayOfWeek == Carbon::FRIDAY || Carbon::parse($record->start_time)->dayOfWeek == Carbon::SATURDAY){
        $fillteredArray[]= $record;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: This way isn't efficient since it run on php, not on database.

Comment: You don't have any method for days not even in Carbon and whereDates() only compares two dates.. see the docs for reference

Comment: You can use `WEEKDAY()` function on database, although it still not the more efficient way it will be better then load all results on PHP then filter the results.

Comment: Mm thats why I preferred to go with `PHP` however does it will work on eloquent??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the model's `$casts` property is properly casting the column to a date, one can easily apply the [filter method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter) using Carbon's `dayOfWeek` property.

```php
/** @var \Illuminate\Support\Collection $events */
$fridays = $events->filter(
    fn ($v, $k) => $v->start_time->dayOfWeek === Carbon::FRIDAY
);
```

Now `$fridays` will only contain those events that started on a Friday. Note the database method detailed in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46734439/1255289) remains more efficient in cases where you have the option to use it, but this may be helpful when extracting a subset from an existing collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

// this will return an array of events
$fridayEvents = $q->start_time;
// assign empty array variable
$dates = [];
//loop on the events 
foreach($fridayEvents as $event){
  // Use carbon to parse make sure it is a date not a string type then reformat it by using format() and the small 'l' inside the format returns the exact name for the day of that date
  // so if it is friday go and push into the array the entire event 
  if(Carbon::parse($event)->format('l') == 'Friday'){
    array_push($dates, $event);
  }
}
// die and dump the data after pushing into the $dates the events
dd($dates);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.